# Spring Boot/Gradle/Logback: bootRun fails with "Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]": java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, logback

In a new Spring Boot application, when I `gradle bootRun`, I see this error:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.EnsureExceptionHandling.process(Lch/qos/logback/core/Context;Lch/qos/logback/core/pattern/Converter;)V
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:86)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder.start(PatternLayoutEncoder.java:28)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator.configure(BasicConfigurator.java:50)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:164)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at com.klarna.risk.decision.application.RiskDecisionApplication.<clinit>(RiskDecisionApplication.java:14)
```

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/release' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:+'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}
apply plugin: 'org.gretty'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/release' }
}

gretty { // for Gradle 4.0+
    springBoot = true
    springBootVersion = '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
group = 'com.example.newapp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/api-test/java']
        }
    }
}
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check with `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency logback`, I see:

```
> Task :dependencyInsight
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library (not requested)

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 8
   ]

ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
\--- compileClasspath

ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 -> 1.1.3
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.1.9.RELEASE
     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.9.RELEASE
          +--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter)
          +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.9.RELEASE
          |    +--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web)
          |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.1.9.RELEASE
          |         \--- compileClasspath
          +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.1.9.RELEASE
          |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.9.RELEASE (*)
          |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:2.1.9.RELEASE
          |         \--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey)
          \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.1.9.RELEASE
               \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:2.1.9.RELEASE (*)

ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library (not requested)

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 8
   ]

ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3 -> 1.2.3
\--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
     +--- compileClasspath
     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.1.9.RELEASE (requested ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3)
          \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.9.RELEASE
               +--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter)
               +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.9.RELEASE
               |    +--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web)
               |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:2.1.9.RELEASE
               |         \--- compileClasspath
               +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.1.9.RELEASE
               |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.9.RELEASE (*)
               |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:2.1.9.RELEASE
               |         \--- compileClasspath (requested org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey)
               \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.1.9.RELEASE
                    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:2.1.9.RELEASE (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.
```

Seems that Spring Boot 2.1.9 is using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.1.9.RELEASE`, which uses `logback-classic:1.1.3`. Somewhere in the Google tells me that Spring Boot dependency management has a bug which permits distinct versions of `logback-core` and `logback-classic` here and causes conflicts.

I added the dependency of `logback-core:1.1.3` and the problem is gone.

```
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.1.3'
```

If you face the same problem, be sure to check the version of logback used in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

Create an logback-test.xml file under resources file along with logback.xml and initialise this new file with just . and it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try to add these 3 dependencies in your pom.xml file. It worked for me..

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```